# chrome devtools 2015 different then 2013 videos

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, timeline

I'm wondering if anyone can fill me in on the history of the timeline tab of the chrome devtools.

I'm currently diving deep into web apps and web site performance in order to fight jankiness (many thanks to Addy Osmany, Paul Irish, and Paul Lewis BTW).  So i'm following video tutorials from http://jankfree.org/, but all the videos are from 2013, and I notice many differences in the presentation of the devtools, but not only...

The most annoying difference is that when I press the record button of the timeline tab, unlike in the videos, the live charts are NOT being drawn while I interact with the page.  The charts are being drawn only once I stop the recording...

If only I could visualize the charts as I interact with the page, it would allow me to better identify which parts of the chart corresponds to my interactions.

I'm on latest stable chrome (version ~41) on MAC, and the latest Iron browser to date, which 'suffers' from the exact same differences.

Comment: BTW: The Iron browser I use runs on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

We can't do live recording any longer, unfortunately.

I would recommend annotating your page with `console.time('this part');` and `console.timeEnd('this part');`

This will allow you to easier associate actions to results.